# Android SQLite: optimize insert duration

Tags: android, database, sqlite, optimization, insert

I'm storing information about user's audio tracks in a database (it's located in internal memory). I have this functions for inserting data in database adapter class:

```
public void addTracks(ArrayList<Track> tracks){
    for (Track track : tracks) {
        addTrack(track);
    }
}

public long addTrack(Track track) {
    ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(track.title, track.artist, 
            track.id, track.url, track.lyrics_id, track.owner_id, track.cover_small_url, track.cover_large_url);
    return database.insert(TABLE_USER_TRACKS, null, initialValues);
}
```

That works fine. However, it takes much time (~10 seconds) when user has several thousands of tracks.

Is there a way to make inserting faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
  db.beginTransaction();
  for (Track track : tracks) 
  {
     addTrack(track);
  }
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch (SQLException e) {}
finally
{
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

Read more about database transactions [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/database-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your inserts into a single transaction, as in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction().
You may try something like this, but be careful about error handling:

```
public void addTracks(ArrayList<Track> tracks){
  database.beginTransaction();
  try {
    for (Track track : tracks) {
      addTrack(track);
    }
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
  } finally {
    database.endTransaction();
  }
}
```